# "The network name cannot be found" error when accessing server path

Tags: c#, path, webclient

I get this error when I try to access server path from remote client. 
The address is in `web.config` file like this

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="RootDirectory" value="\\ipaddress/root\"/>
</appSettings>
```

Its retrieved like this

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootDirectory"] != null){
    root = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootDirectory"];
}

public static string RequiredScvFilesLocation{
    get { return root + @"blabla\"; }
}
```

and called like this

```
string[] requiredFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Globals.Common.RequiredScvFilesLocation,"*.svc.zip").ToArray();
```

Error comes at the last code piece

Comment: Can you tell why did you downvote this?

Answer (score 1):

Please make changes in path and try.

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="RootDirectory" value="\\ipaddress\root\"/>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved when I share the filepath in server IIS. I didn't think I needed that as long as sufficient permissions are given to `IIS_IUSRS`.

Answer (score 0):

There Must be backslash () also in your path Not slash (/)

Comment: Can you possibly add a source or an explanation on why this should work? Thank you.